# POCO Aliases for a database that has non-standard naming conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I have a database that I'm working with that has each column named something like "product_id", "event_tracking_detail_type", etc.

Instead of using title case its all lower case and has _ between names. I've turned off code generation and used the POCO generator but I'd like to have the POCOs be named something along the lines of ProductId, ManufacturerImage (instead of manufacturer_image).

Is there a way to have the POCOs have different names then what is actually in the database, like an alias or something?

My reasons is to have the code interact with the proper names then down the road change the column names for the database.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the MSDN documentation on data annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). You can use the `Table` and `Column` attributes.

```
[Column(Name="product_id")]
Int32 ProductId;
```

Or, you can use the [fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295845%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) ([here are samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx))

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITYNAME>() 
.Property(entity=>entity.ProductId) 
.HasColumnName("product_id")
```

Comment: Is there a more generic way then doing it for each column and table? I have 50+ tables to do this on :S

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the T4 Templates, there is a function `WriteProprety` you can modify that writes out properties.  You could modify it something like:

```
void WriteProperty(string accessibility, string type, string name, string getterAccessibility,  string setterAccessibility)
{
  //Start New Stuff
  string[] names = name.Split('_');
  names = names.ToList().Select(x => char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1)).ToArray();
  string fixedName = string.Join("", names);
 //End New Stuff
#>
  [Column(Name="<#=name>")]
  <#=accessibility#> <#=type#> <#=fixedName#> { <#=getterAccessibility#>get; <#=setterAccessibility#>set; }
<#+
}
```